# Does including <QtGUI> in every class cause overhead?

Tags: c++, qt, header

When I create classes which implement QWidget, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsItem etc... I always just include QtGui instead of QtWidget, QGraphicsView etc... is this bad practice? Is there any performance cost? Is build time longer because of this?

Comment: Usually I include QtGui when I'm designing and testing a class; then when I'm done I just include only the necessary headers so it won't slow down compile time in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `QtGui` header includes all other headers, then *compile* time will be longer, as the compilers pre-processor has to read more files and the compiler itself will have more classes/structures to parse and keep track of. However, *linking* time and more importantly *runtime*  will not be affected.